# Div responsive with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Want to  change the order of occurrence Of these two divs. Here the div with id=1 is first in all the devices by default, Now what I want is that the div with id =2 should display first for all small screen devices for example in tablet and mobile devices, But for desktop i want the same sequence like it is right now.
Below is the code.

```
<div class="container main-padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8" id="1">
            <div class="page-body-title">MISSIONS DE L'IGF</div>

            <br>
            <p>L'IGF a pour missions:</p>

            <br>


            <div class="page-body-title"> ATTRIBUTIONS DE L'IGF</div>

            <br>
            <p>
                Les attributions générales de l'IGF sont les suivantes:
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 " id="2">

            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <p class="inside-page-right">ACCUEIL  &#62; <i class="active">A PROPOS</i></p>
                <br>
                <div class="col-lg-12 inside-page-bbox">
                    <div class="bbox">
                        <span><a href="mission_et_attributions">&#43; &nbsp;&nbsp;Mission et Attributions </a></span><br>
                        <span><a href="organisation">&#43; &nbsp;&nbsp;Organisation </a></span><br>
                        <span><a href="perimetre_d_intervention">&#43; &nbsp;&nbsp;Perimètre d'intervention </a></span><br>
                        <span><a href="type_d_intervention">&#43; &nbsp;&nbsp;Type d'intervention </a></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Columns must always be *directly* inside `.row`. To nest columns use `row>col>row>col` instead of `row>col>col`

Comment: And check [column ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Comment: Do you need two columns in same row on small devices (side by side with order reversed div with  id=2 then id=1) or you need them one(id=2) on top of other(id=1) ?

Comment: i want 2 different rows in small devices. Thanks for replying. I got the solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Bootstrap's [Grid Column Ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering). I've given an example that might work for you, below.

```html
<div class="container main-padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-8" id="2">

            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <p class="inside-page-right">ACCUEIL  &#62; <i class="active">A PROPOS</i></p>
                <br>
                <div class="col-lg-12 inside-page-bbox">
                    <div class="bbox">
                        <span><a href="mission_et_attributions">&#43; &nbsp;&nbsp;Mission et Attributions </a></span><br>
                        <span><a href="organisation">&#43; &nbsp;&nbsp;Organisation </a></span><br>
                        <span><a href="perimetre_d_intervention">&#43; &nbsp;&nbsp;Perimètre d'intervention </a></span><br>
                        <span><a href="type_d_intervention">&#43; &nbsp;&nbsp;Type d'intervention </a></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-push-4" id="1">
            <div class="page-body-title">MISSIONS DE L'IGF</div>

            <br>
            <p>L'IGF a pour missions:</p>

            <br>


            <div class="page-body-title"> ATTRIBUTIONS DE L'IGF</div>

            <br>
            <p>
                Les attributions générales de l'IGF sont les suivantes:
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what i want was div id=2 to come in first place for just small devices like tablet and div id=1  in second place for desktop

Comment: That's exactly what the example above will do. I assumed, based on the classes you supplied - that you were using Bootstrap v3; which is a mobile-first framework. So, pages are laid out for mobile, and the css adjusts for desktops. Try the code in your project, and let me know if it does what you require.

Comment: Thanks Appreciate the reply and solution. :)